# libgdx crashes on android fine on desktop

Tags: class, libgdx, main-activity

my Libgdx project works fine on the desktop but crashes on android genymotion emulator.

my main activity doesn't seem to instatiate:
`04-17 19:20:11.537: W/dalvikvm(1075): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/me/mygdxgame/MainActivity;)`

and following things through the error seems to be: 
`04-17 19:20:11.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1075): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gdx: findLibrary returned null`

i have min api 8 and target 19.  I've tried running on api levels 18 and 10.
googling suggested a buildpath problem but I have everything ticked under ORDER AND EXPORT.

Anyone know what the problem might be?  I'm a noob and I have know clue how to about investigating further. would it be worth recreating the project with libgdx setup-ui?

here is some of the log.  not sure how much text i am allowed here... the full log is 80k...
i posted it here

```
<a href="http://wikisend.com/download/503994/stack_trace_android_140418.txt">http://wikisend.com/download/503994/stack_trace_android_140418.txt</a>

04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874): No connection to daemon
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874): java.lang.IllegalStateException
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874):  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.sendCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:200)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874):  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.sendCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:186)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874):  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.doCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:224)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874):  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.doListCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:270)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874):  at com.android.server.MountService$2.run(MountService.java:576)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/MountService(1874): Error processing initial volume state
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/MountService(1874): com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException: No output stream!
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/MountService(1874):   at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.sendCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:201)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/MountService(1874):   at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.sendCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:186)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/MountService(1874):   at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.doCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:224)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/MountService(1874):   at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.doListCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:270)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/MountService(1874):   at com.android.server.MountService$2.run(MountService.java:576)
04-18 09:56:32.020: W/MountService(1874): Duplicate state transition (removed -> removed)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874): No connection to daemon
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874): java.lang.IllegalStateException
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874):  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.sendCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:200)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874):  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.sendCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:186)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874):  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.doCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:224)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874):  at com.android.server.MountService.doGetShareMethodAvailable(MountService.java:798)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874):  at com.android.server.MountService.access$1300(MountService.java:76)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/VoldConnector(1874):  at com.android.server.MountService$2.run(MountService.java:611)
04-18 09:56:32.020: E/MountService(1874): Failed to determine whether share method ums is available.
04-18 09:56:32.090: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1850): setPhoneState() setting same state 0
04-18 09:56:32.100: E/SoundPool(1874): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-18 09:56:32.100: W/AudioService(1874): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-18 09:56:32.100: E/SoundPool(1874): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
04-18 09:56:32.100: W/AudioService(1874): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
04-18 09:56:32.100: E/SoundPool(1874): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
04-18 09:56:32.100: W/AudioService(1874): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
04-18 09:56:32.100: E/SoundPool(1874): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
04-18 09:56:32.100: W/AudioService(1874): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
04-18 09:56:32.100: E/SoundPool(1874): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
04-18 09:56:32.100: W/AudioService(1874): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
```

Comment: I should mention I haven't set any permissions in the manifest. (my app doesn't 'do' anything outside of draw stuff so i left them as default)

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace?  The `UnsatisfiedLinkError` may have been caused by an exception that provides more details.

Comment: would it be feasible to create an audio version of particle effect i.e. something built up a custom sfx by emitting smaller explosions sounds?

Comment: i can't post the whole thing it's too long.  there are other errors.  sometime before the fatal error i get the errors which I don't understand.  for one thing i don't know anything about the ogg files mentioned.